Ubuntu 20.04 login fails (one more time)
My Ubuntu 20.04 suddenly stopped coming up.  I enter a password, things
crank for a bit, and then I am asked for a password again.  This can go on
and on.
I am able to bring up 16.04, and using it, I have done a bit of sleuthing, I
have determined the following: The attempt to being up 20.04 creates the
following files in /var/log
auth.log
boot.log
gpu-manager.log
kern.log
mail.err
mail.lor
syslog
wtmp.log
Xorg.0.log

Using grep I have checked for the word "error" (case-insensitive) and it is
found only in kern.log, mail.err, and syslog.  Attached are these files:
mail.err
kern.err (error lines from kern.log)
syslog.err (error lines from syslog - entire syslog available if requested)

I would greatly appreciate any enlightenment about what is going on and how
to fix it.
Roger House
Software Developer
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

mail.err

May 21 15:43:01 ada sm-mta[1735]: My unqualified host name (ada) unknown; sleeping for retry
May 21 15:43:03 ada sm-msp-queue[1818]: My unqualified host name (ada) unknown; sleeping for retry
May 21 15:44:01 ada sm-mta[1735]: unable to qualify my own domain name (ada) -- using short name
May 21 15:44:03 ada sm-msp-queue[1818]: unable to qualify my own domain name (ada) -- using short name

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

kern.err

May 21 15:42:56 ada kernel: [    3.352957] EXT4-fs (sdb6): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
May 21 15:42:57 ada NetworkManager[1039]: <warn>  [1716331377.0371] failed to enumerate oFono devices: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

syslog.err

May 21 15:42:56 ada kernel: [    3.352957] EXT4-fs (sdb6): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
May 21 15:42:56 ada gpu-manager[1040]: Error: can't open /lib/modules/4.4.0-179-generic/updates/dkms
May 21 15:42:56 ada gpu-manager[1040]: Error: can't open /lib/modules/4.4.0-179-generic/updates/dkms
May 21 15:42:56 ada gpu-manager[1040]: update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for x86_64-linux-gnu_gfxcore_conf
May 21 15:42:56 ada unattended-upgrade-shutdown[1216]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_dbus_bindings'
May 21 15:42:57 ada NetworkManager[1039]: <warn>  [1716331377.0371] failed to enumerate oFono devices: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
May 21 15:43:02 ada udev-configure-printer[1567]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cups'
May 21 15:43:02 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 21 15:43:03 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 21 15:43:04 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 21 15:43:05 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 21 15:43:06 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool ntp.ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 21 15:43:08 ada org.a11y.Bus[1978]: ** (process:2065): WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
May 21 15:43:19 ada snapd[997]: stateengine.go:150: state ensure error: Get https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/sections: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:33159->[::1]:53: read: connection refused
May 21 15:43:37 ada pulseaudio[2096]: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
May 21 15:44:06 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 21 15:44:08 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 21 15:44:09 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 21 15:44:10 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool ntp.ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 21 15:44:11 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 21 15:45:12 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 21 15:45:13 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 21 15:45:14 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 21 15:45:15 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool ntp.ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 21 15:45:18 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 21 15:46:17 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 21 15:46:20 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 21 15:46:21 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 21 15:46:22 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool ntp.ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 21 15:46:24 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 21 15:47:23 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 21 15:47:25 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 21 15:47:27 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool ntp.ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 21 15:47:27 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 21 15:47:30 ada ntpd[1699]: error resolving pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)


Please be clear with details; you mention 20.04 LTS but don't actually give any product details (is this Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server? Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop?) as desktop uses a GUI which has extra requirements that don't exist on a server system (ie. sufficient free space needs to exist in $HOME for a GUI login to proceed, otherwise login is aborted & login loop is expected result..)

Does this answer your question? Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop

Did you check ~/.xsession-errors? Did you grep for anything other than the string error? AFAIK errors in the Xorg.N.log files would be indicated by (EE)
